# How do I prevent an invalid operation on a possible null reference in typescript?

Tags: typescript, flowtype, nullable, type-safety

Consider this example where `a` is possibly `null`, and is explicitly declared so. Even with strict null checks enabled, typescript does not warn me about a possible error here -

```
let a: string | null = "hello"

function b() {
  a = null
}

b()

a.replace('2', '3')
```

Link to the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20%22hello%22%0A%0Afunction%20b()%20%7B%0A%20%20a%20%3D%20null%0A%7D%0A%0Ab()%0A%0Aa.replace('2'%2C%20'3')).

The same code written in flow would have immediately errored out as the `replace` method is not available for a `null` type.

What can I do ensure type-safety in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are explicitly allowing null values, you need to consider handling this behavior manually. hence, you may use this

```
(a || '').replace('2', '3');
```

Comment: I understand that. But why doesn't typescript consider this as a type error in the first place?